# Update and delete queries do not have any effect

Tags: hibernate

I have the following update and delete queries using Hibernate:

```
public boolean update(CuentaUsuario usuario) {
    boolean flag = false;
    Session sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = sesion.beginTransaction();
    try {
        CuentaUsuario usuariodb = (CuentaUsuario) sesion.load(CuentaUsuario.class, usuario.getIdcuentaUsuario());
        usuariodb.setUsername(usuario.getUsername());
        usuariodb.setIdRol(usuario.getIdRol());
        usuariodb.setCorreo(usuario.getCorreo());
        sesion.saveOrUpdate(usuariodb);
        tx.commit();
        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

When they are invoked, they do not seem to have any effect. The data isn't actually been updated or deleted in the DB.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please edit your post to state what problem you're having. "dont want update or delete" doesn't tell us anything. When you're finished with that, please edit your post to be [more concise](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @patstuart thank u , i'll do now ...

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that caught my attention when reading your code was:

```
sesion.beginTransaction();
// ...    
sesion.beginTransaction().commit();
// ...
sesion.beginTransaction().rollback();
```

So basically what you are doing here is:

- "start a new transaction"
- "start a new transaction and immediately commit it"
- "start a new transaction and immediately perform a rollback"

That does not make any sense. You should not start a new transaction everytime on commit and rollback, but perform it on the initially started transaction. Your concrete problem is caused because you never commits the real transaction.

A usual approach would be:

```
Transaction tx = null;
try{
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    // perform some operations on your entities
    tx.commit();
}
catch(SomeException ex){
    if(tx != null){
        tx.rollback();
    }
}
```

Maybe there are more errors in the code. I didn't take a deeper look at it.
Maybe this already solves your problem. Otherwise we have to inspect it further.

Comment: thank u for your fast answer , now ... with your help my code was so
but this doesn't works man , send me an error "Tx" variable might not have been initialized ...

Comment: nothing happnes guys , i tried everythring  but the problem persist , the queries dont have any effect :/ !

Comment: Please edit your initial post to the latest version of your code and tell us what happens.